# Global Address Class information

Tags: class, street-address

I am trying to create a generic address class that could be used to store any address from any country.

For example here in the UK we have post code where as in USA I think they use Zip code.
I have few ideas in mind but I just wanted to see what others think.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for quick answers. Initially my website will be launched in the UK, people should be able to search by postcode, city or any other parts of address information. Once user choose their country then they will be ask to enter the relevant information for that country(Zipcode instead of postcode)

Comment: I am also trying to develop Global Address class did you find solution?

Comment: No, I still have not found any good solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on what level of detail you want. For instance, do you need to geocode addresses - producing an identifier that geographically locates the address? Do you need to validate that the address exists? Do you need to be able to convert the address to the standard format for the national postal authority?

If you need these features, then you need more than your own class - you need a third-party product.

I'd mention one, but although it did these things, it was unpleasant, to say the least. Google "Data Quality", "Address Standardization", "Data Profiling" and things like that.

Comment: I will probably also need to show the addresses on map (e.g. google map) so geocode is important. you mentioned third party ? What products are available out there ? That might help.
Thanks.

Comment: If I were you, I'd Google this. Try http://search.live.com/results.aspx?q=%22address+cleansing%22&form=QBRE. I checked the company I mentioned, and they still look quite bad. Their idea of Microsoft ETL is "DTS".

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to use that class. If you want to display all addresses within a specified locality (e.g. 'North America'), you might want to think about some kind of hierarchy. If you just want to print addresses, you might have to accept the huge variability and just store address as a big string.